# Run additional service on domain with Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: multisite, htaccess, web-services

I've got three parked domains configured to use my WordPress Multisite installation.  No problems with the configurations there.  I can serve up three independent WordPress blogs at `site1.com`, `site2.com`, `site3.com`.  All WordPress files are located in my web root at `/public_html`.

What I'd like to do is add a completely separate service to one of my sites.  For example, let's say I want to run the Foo Service that I've installed in a subdirectory of my web root (`public_html/foo_service`), and I want visitors to be able to browse to `site1.com/foo` in order to access that service.  How do I "escape" the WordPress configuration?  Do I configure a different site within my WordPress network?  Can I add some redirect to my root .htaccess?

The way my .htaccess is configured now, it would appear that anything I append to my URL is routed through WordPress' index.php.

Here's my current `.htaccess`:

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/user123/public_html/php.ini
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```